# Happy number: is loop really possible?

Tags: number-theory

I try to solving [leetcode problem #202](https://leetcode.com/problems/happy-number/) about "Happy number" and wondering is really infinit loop is possible:

> A happy number is a number defined by the following process:
>
> Starting with any positive integer, replace the number by the sum of
> the squares of its digits.
>
> Repeat the process until the number equals 1 (where it will stay), or
> **it loops endlessly in a cycle which does not include 1**.
>
> Those numbers for which this process ends in 1 are happy.

Classic way contains no loop detector (HashSet or similar data structures).

I've [checked all numbers upto Int32.MaxValue](https://leetcode.com/problems/happy-number/discuss/1064286/C-Without-HashSet) but can't detect any loop. Is is really possible? I tried to proove by induction that it's not possible, but failed.

Comment: $4, 16, 37, 58, 89, 145, 42, 20, 4$, from https://oeis.org/A000216

Comment: Also $9,81,65,61,37$ after which one enters the loop above.

Comment: Could have saved a lot of effort by seeing that the result after 1 step is at most 1 + 9x81 = 730

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The sum of squares of its digits brings large numbers down by a lot. Namely, given a number with n digits, the maximal next value it can attain is $81n$. This is because if you have a number with $n$ nines, the sum will be $9^2 + 9^2 + ... n$ times. You can now use the fact that a number a has $\lceil\log_{10}(a)\rceil$
digits. Solving $\lceil\log_{10}(a)\rceil< a$ gives $243$ as a bound for which no number above can possibly be contained in a loop. All you have to do now is check all number up to $243$, and you're done.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).